# Form using spring, change value of radio button

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

I have bean like this:

```
class StudentBean
{
    ...
    private String gender = "Male";
    ...
    // setters and getters here
}
```

The Spring form is something like this:

```
<!-- Gender -->
<form:form action="url" method="POST" modelAttribute="studentBean">
     <form:radiobutton path="gender" id="male" value="Male" required="required" style="float:left;" checked="checked"/> 
     <form:radiobutton path="gender" id="female" value="Female" required="required" style="float:left;"/>
...
</form:form>
```

The gender radio button by default is set to **Male**, I want to change it using jQuery.

What I tried so far is:

`$('.gender[value="'+ beanList[index].myGender +'"]').prop('checked', true);`

it also the same with

`$('.gender[value="Female"]').prop('checked', true);`

**But doesn't change the radio button. What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Shouldn't you be changing it to `"checked"` instead of `true`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Isn't that is used for `attr()` ?

Comment: `gender` isn't a class, but you're using a jQuery class selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of JQuery are you using and in what browser?  FYI - You question appears to really be isolated to JQuery and what has already been rendered to the browser, so you may want to take off the spring related tags.

try making the change like this:
$("input[value='Female']").prop('checked',true);

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
  <input type="radio" path="gender" id="Male" name="sex" value="Male" checked="checked" />Male
  <br />
  <input type="radio" path="gender" id="Female" name="sex" value="Female" />Female
  <div id="test">my test</div>
</form>

<script>
alert("hello");
$("input[value='Female']").prop('checked',true);
alert("bye");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`gender` isn't a class, but you're using a jQuery class selector.

Try this instead:

```
$("input[name='gender'][value='Female']").prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting things with the gender *class* (the . prefix is class), whereas gender is an ID in your HTML. You could either change the selector to target the ID gender

```
($('#gender[value="Female"]').prop('checked', true);)
```

or you could add classes to your HTML like this:

```
<!-- Gender -->
<form:form action="url" method="POST" modelAttribute="studentBean">
<form:radiobutton path="gender" class="male" value="Male" required="required" style="float:left;" checked="checked"/> 
<form:radiobutton path="gender" class="female" value="Female" required="required" style="float:left;"/>
...
</form:form>
```

The correct solution depends on how many times an element will appear on the page. Multiple elements can have the same class, but only one element on a page can have any ID. If you're going to have multiple copies of this form, and therefore multiple gender radio buttons, then change the IDs to classes. If this form will only appear once then IDs are okay.